# 'Perpetual motion' paper by George Biddell Airy

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion

Airy wrote a paper (maybe deceptively) titled *[On certain Conditions under which a Perpetual Motion is possible](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xQEBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA369&lpg=PA369&dq=%22On%20certain%20Conditions%20under%20which%20a%20Perpetual%20Motion%20is%20possible%22&source=bl&ots=kB1fVOhU-r&sig=ACfU3U3ku4htpAHRGmrsVLmKWEvyVY5e4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw8-7-ztPpAhWFlFwKHXOEBt8Q6AEwA3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22On%20certain%20Conditions%20under%20which%20a%20Perpetual%20Motion%20is%20possible%22&f=false)* (Cambridge Philosophical Transactions, December 14, 1829). Alternative site (in more than one sense) with JPEG images: https://www.besslerwheel.com/airy/. I've OCRed the (very legible) images and I can post the text here if required.

As a jack of all trades and master of none (I have read and understood *The Theoretical Minimum* by Susskind and Hrabovsky), I found the paper rather dense. Can somebody summarize it in modern language?

Comment: Precis: Air passing through a flexible reed can cause sound.  Nothing about perpetiual motion except the misleading title!

Comment: @mikestone, thanks! Are you interested in expanding your comment to an answer?

Comment: Not really! The understanding  as to how wind instruments make sound has developed a great deal since Airy, and his theory, although a nice bit diff-eq theory  is quite obsolete.

Comment: @mikestone, sorry. Thanks again.

Comment: The author of the paper is accurate in *deducing* the effects of his postulated law of force in the particular phenomenon. However on page 3 they note that the postulates are not backed up by experiment.

Comment: Re *I found the paper rather dense* -- Try reading Newton's *Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica*, which he wrote in Latin. Every English translation looks like Greek to me. Or try reading James Maxwell's *A Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism*. While written in English, it is still ... Greek. Almost all profession writing regarding physics before the late 19th century will inevitably be a bit inscrutable because those writers did use modern mathematical notation. And almost all profession writing regarding physics since the late 19th century will be more than a bit dense.

Comment: @DavidHammen, "Try reading Newton's...". Well, I *tried*... and I returned the book to the library.

Comment: It's probably worth knowing there's a sibling question over at https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47693/did-george-biddell-airy-write-a-paper-on-certain-conditions-under-which-a-perpe

Comment: @KyleMiller, I asked about the authenticity of the paper because the title and first paragraphs are a bit... *weird*.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Sure, but I think it's good for others to be aware that there is discussion in two places.

Comment: @mikestone, see the answer (AND the comment) by https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/265876/kyle-miller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He considers the differential equation
$$\phi''(t)=-e \phi(t)-g\phi(t-c),$$
which models a body acted upon by a force whose magnitude depends on the body's "position at some time preceding that action" (quoted from the second paragraph).  He is inspired by an analysis of vocal chords by someone named Mr. Willis.

If $g=0$, this is a run-of-the-mill second order linear differential equation, and it has the solution $$\phi(t)=a\sin(t\sqrt{e}+b)$$ for $a$ and $b$ arbitrary constants.

But with $g>0$ it is difficult to solve, and I'm unaware of a theorem that proves a solution even exists.  He refers to another paper that (presumably; I didn't check it myself) gives a formula for a small-$g$ approximation, and then he describes, using their notation, how to calculate the increase in amplitude from cycle to cycle.  This corresponds to an increase in energy in the system.

**Commentary.** A way to think about this differential equation is that it is modeling a driven simple harmonic oscillator without damping and with driving force $-g\phi(t-c)$.  If $g$ is small, then in the short term the system has the characteristics of an undriven simple harmonic oscillator, thus operates at its natural frequency.  The driving force is a phase-shifted version of its position, which in particular is at the natural frequency, and driving a simple harmonic oscillator at its natural frequency causes resonance.

The ability of the system to drive itself is probably where the energy is coming from, since the system is having to do work to apply this force through time.  What I mean is, it takes external energy to apply this force.

**In short:** it is a paper about an approximate solution to a second-order differential equation that was inspired by some contemporaneous research.

Comment: Thanks. And, according to a private comment, "Nothing about perpetual motion except the misleading title!". Do you agree?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I can't say without knowing more context about what they were thinking about back then.  For all I know, Airy's paper is a polite way of saying Willis's proposal that vocal chord motion involves a force depending on their past position should be dismissed because such a law would lead to perpetual motion.

Comment: "... a polite way of saying Willis's proposal..." +1000! (factorial, not exclamation).